How are cookies set? - React.js & Node.js
Description:
I am using Oauth 2.0 for my react app. When I get google login consent from users, the redirect url is 'http://localhost:3000/google/auth' where I handle the getting access token , registering / logging user & sending JWT cookies parts.
The JWT cookie is set to http://localhost:5173 which is my vite react front-end and I am struggling to understand how this cookie is set, because the request actually comes from the google consent page to google/auth route and not from localhost:5173 frontend.
Does the cookie always get set to the original host from which the request came ultimately from?
My node.js backend controllers: 
oAuthrRedrect (/oauth) takes care of serving front-end login page with Auth server url.
oAuthCallback (/google/auth) takes care of callback from consent page
logIn (sub-function) performs creation / logging in of user, setting JWT cookie, etc.
const oAuthRedirect = async (req, res) => {
    const state = "some_state";
    const scopes = GOOGLE_OAUTH_SCOPES.join(" ");
    const GOOGLE_OAUTH_CONSENT_SCREEN_URL = `${GOOGLE_OAUTH_URL}?client_id=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL}&access_type=offline&response_type=code&state=${state}&scope=${scopes}`;
    res.send(GOOGLE_OAUTH_CONSENT_SCREEN_URL);
    // window.location.href=GOOGLE_OAUTH_CONSENT_SCREEN_URL;
}

const logIn = async (email, profilePic, { req, res }) => {
    try {
        const data = await userModel.exists({ username: email });
        console.log(data)
        if (!data) throw "userNotExist"
        // Creating JWT cookie for user
        var id = data._id;
        const token = jwt.sign({ id }, 'bar', { expiresIn: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 });
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
            withCredentials: true,
            httpOnly: false,
            maxAge: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        });
        res.status(200).json({
            userId: data._id,
            message: "User is welcome!",
        })
        // res.redirect('http://localhost:5173/homepage');
    } catch (err) {
        if (err == 'userNotExist') {
            userModel.create({ username: email }).then((data) => {
                console.log("User doesn't exist")
                var id = data._id;
                const token = jwt.sign({ id }, 'bar', { expiresIn: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 });
                res.cookie("jwt", token, {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    httpOnly: false,
                    maxAge: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                });
                res.status(200).json({
                    userId: id,
                    message: "User is welcome!",
                })
            })
        }
    }
}

const oAuthCallback = async (req, res) => {
    //  Getting authentication code
    var { code } = req.query;
    var data = {
        code,
        client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,

        client_secret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,

        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/google/auth",

        grant_type: "authorization_code",
    }

    // Getting access token
    const response = await fetch(GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, {
        method: "POST",

        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    try {
        const access_token_data = await response.json();
        if (access_token_data.error) {
            throw access_token_data.error
        }
        var accessToken = access_token_data.access_token;
        if (access_token_data.refresh_token) var refreshToken = access_token_data.refresh_token
        var idToken = access_token_data.id_token
        console.log("Access token: " + accessToken + "\n" + "refreshToken: " + (refreshToken ? refreshToken : '\n') + "Id token: " + idToken);

        //  Getting token information
        var tokenInfoResponse = await fetch(GOOGLE_TOKEN_INFO_URL + "?id_token=" + idToken);
        tokenInfoResponse = await tokenInfoResponse.json();

        var email = tokenInfoResponse.email;
        var profilePic = tokenInfoResponse.picture;
        logIn(email, profilePic, { req: req, res: res });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error + "This is an error");
    }
}

Front end functions:
 // Go handling social button click
    const handleSocialLogin = async (e, socialLoginType) => {
        console.log(socialLoginType);
        socialLoginMediator();
    }

    const socialLoginMediator =  async () =>{
        try {
            // Getting auth url for social loginj
            const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/oauth")
            const authUrl = data;
            // Showing consent page
            window.location.href=authUrl
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

Sign In page

The consent page:
This is from where the callback url which I set as http://localhost:3000/google/auth is called from.

I need to know how the cookie was set to localhost:5173 when the request was made from google's page 
Also, I could use any directions as to how I can get a good understanding of these concepts and how everything under the hood work.
Thank you!
